# How to clone a Date object?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Assigning a `Date` variable to another one will copy the reference to the same instance. This means that changing one will change the other.

How can I actually clone or copy a `Date` instance?

Answer (score 1047, accepted):

Use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object's [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method, which returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC ([epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)):

```
var date = new Date();
var copiedDate = new Date(date.getTime());
```

In Safari 4, you can also write:

```
var date = new Date();
var copiedDate = new Date(date);
```

...but I'm not sure whether this works in other browsers. (It seems to work in IE8).

Comment: Sometimes people also use JSON serialization and deserialization, but this one is better and much faster. +1 from me.

Comment: JSON for this snippet? Sounds like these people should get their basics clear... Like mistaking jQuery for JavaScript DOM.

Comment: Another way to write this nice solution would be to extend the Date prototype:

`Date.prototype.clone = function() { return new Date(this.getTime()); };`

Which you could then use as `copiedDate = date.clone();`

Comment: The `copiedDate = new Date(date)` approach works in IE6+. In Firefox the two options are the same speed.

Comment: `new Date(date)` same as `new Date(date.getTime())`, because JS will try to call `date.valueOf()` when it need a number, and `date.valueOf()` is same as `date.getTime()`, reference [Date.valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FvalueOf) [Object.valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FvalueOf)

Comment: Instead of `date.getTime()`, you can do `+date` to cast it to a number with less characters.

Comment: What about dates that start before 1970 ?

Comment: Do not use `new Date(date)`, use `new Date(date.getTime()` or `new Date(date.valueOf)` instead since the first way can lead to differences between the dates in at least Firefox and IE (not Chrome). For example using `toISOString()` on the both dates in Firefox generates `"2015-04-21T04:56:42.000Z"` and `"2015-04-21T04:56:42.337Z"`.

Comment: `new Date(dateObject)` is **correct**. See description of [Date(value) constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value) where explicit rules for date object is defined. In the older specs the behavior was to call `ToNumber` on the argument if it wasn't a string so either way this should work in any browser that implements the behavior correctly.

Comment: Please don't extend the Date prototype. Please. Picture what would happen if everyone extended prototypes. Nothing good.

Comment: @user2555515 Works for me in chrome: `new Date(new Date().setDate(-100000)).toString()` evaluates to `Tue Jan 16 1748 15:57:44 GMT-0517 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Comment: @SalmanA—careful. Noting that this answer was written in 2009, prior to ECMA 2011 (ed 5), `ToPrimitive(Date)` returned a string and in IE at least `new Date(Date)` returned a different date in some cases because it didn't correctly parse the string generated by its own *toString* method. Also, where *toString* produced a two digit year or year less than 100, it was shifted to 1900 + year. Hence the use of `new Date(+Date)` to ensure the time value was returned always. Though in 2021 likely it's safe to rely on *ToPrimitive*. :-)

Answer (score 180):

This is the cleanest approach

```js
let date = new Date() 
let copyOfDate = new Date(date.valueOf())

console.log(date);
console.log(copyOfDate);
```

Comment: The "valueOf()" method for "Date" objects produces the same result as its "getTime()" method (the number of milliseconds since epoch time).

Comment: @Steve: true,  but getTime() could "looks" like it only returns the time and not include the date as well hence my reference to "cleanest".  Frankly the Date type in Javascript is a bit of disaster zone, it should never have been mutable in the first place.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Right, I see what you mean.

Comment: I agree that .valueOf() is more clear. Sometimes I forget and use .getMilliseconds() b/c to me that sounds like it means mean milliseconds since epoch time.

Comment: +1 to Steve Harrison: I was wondering if that was the case, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 88):

### Update for 2021

In one respect the notion of cloning a `Date` object sounds grander than it really is. As far as I can tell, there’s only one piece of instance data, and that is the stored time. What we’re really doing is making a new object with the same time.

Whatever may have been the case in the past, the `new Date()` constructor definitely accepts a `Date` object as a single argument:

```js
const date = new Date();        // With or without an argument.
const date2 = new Date(date);   // Clone original date.
```

The Specification at https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date at step 4(b) indicates that a `Date` object is definitely acceptable, and that this is equivalent to `new Date(date.valueOf())`, as suggested by some of the answers above. As I said, all you’re really doing is making a new `Date` object with the same time as the other.

You’ll also find that the documentation  at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date has been updated to include this.

Answer (score 40):

```js
var orig = new Date();
var copy = new Date(+orig);

console.log(orig, copy);
```

Comment: I like this solution the best.

Comment: Very precise and clean :)

Comment: Except you'll have to explain what that magic `+` is doing to anyone but JS experts.

Comment: :) `+` sign is unaray operator here. It means ``new Date( Number(orig)) `` . More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: Only works if `orig` is not a string such as `2020-09-02T06:49:51.4000654Z`

Comment: @TetraDev As you can see in this example it is not a string. :)

Answer (score 15):

Simplified version:

```
Date.prototype.clone = function () {
    return new Date(this.getTime());
}
```

Comment: thou shalt not mess with built-in objects

Comment: Thou shalt not mess with objects thou dost not owneth. You should make a new copy and call it SuperDate or something, withing your scope. Lots of hard to test for bugs are caused by object functionality changing unexpectedly.

Comment: This would work, but for maintainability reasons, This approach would be considered as a code smell. I have written an approach that I usually use in my coding: https://actuts.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/cloning-javascript-date-instances/

Comment: Also I don't see this need for trying to add methods to built-ins in the first place. Study [functional programming](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript) and discover why a good old-fashioned function is actually much more powerful than methods on the object itself. It's also shorter: `const cloneDate = d => new Date(d.getTime())`.

Answer (score 11):

I found out that this simple assignmnent also works:

```
dateOriginal = new Date();
cloneDate = new Date(dateOriginal);
```

But I don't know how "safe" it is. Successfully tested in IE7 and Chrome 19.

Comment: Do not use `new Date(date)`, use `new Date(date.getTime()` or `new Date(date.valueOf)` instead since the first way can lead to differences between the dates in at least Firefox and IE (not Chrome). For example using `toISOString()` on the both dates in Firefox generates `"2015-04-21T04:56:42.000Z"` and `"2015-04-21T04:56:42.337Z"`.

Comment: That may have been true on old versions of firefox, but on the latest version, `new Date(date)` works fine. Try it: `let date = '2015-04-21T04:56:42.337Z'; new Date(date).toISOString()`. Result is the same as input: `"2015-04-21T04:56:42.337Z"`

Comment: To anyone reading this nowadays, this **works**, please ignore old comments stating that `.getTime` must be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cloneMyDate(oldDate){
  var newDate = new Date(this.oldDate);
}
```

I was passing oldDate to function and generating newDate from this.oldDate, but it was changing this.oldDate also.So i used the above solution and it worked.

Answer (score -4):

For chrome it works:

//Thu Nov 03 2022 11:43:00

**const date = new Date(2022,10,03,11,43,0);

const date2 = new Date(date);**

now changing date2 will have no impact on the date

Comment: Please learn how to [use markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and adjust your answer accordingly.

Comment: The formatting isn’t the only problem with this answer. It contains something that has already been covered by all previous answers.