# Setting object by value instead of reference

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to init a var in JS with date from another JS object but whatever i am trying getting reference to the old object (pointer) and I need it not to change.

```
var lastActionDate = new Date(mainLastActionDate);
var nowDate = new Date();
var tmpLastActionDate = lastActionDate;

if ((tmpLastActionDate.setDate(tmpLastActionDate.getDate() + 7)) > nowDate)
```

The last line is the problematic line. I thought that lastActionDate should not be changed and i need it to stay with the old date, but it changes with tmpLastActionDate and i am guessing because it is a pointer.

How can one set a date object by value instead of reference?

Comment: Could you please post some code? I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: Use a copy: `var tmpLastActionDate = new Date(lastActionDate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
d=new Date()
e=new Date(d.valueOf())
```

Comment: So simple, thank you, in 5 minutes i will mark your answer as the correct one....so simple, valueOf, stupid me :-)

Comment: @camus—you can just do `e - new Date(d);`, no need for `valueOf` or `getTime`.

Comment: I Think I've tried that and didn't work, don't know why....but this one works, 10x

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone your original Date object.
You can use this method :

```
var date = new Date();
var copiedDate = new Date(date.getTime());
```

Reference: [How to clone a Date object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript)