# .clone is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to get the start date of a day and the end date. Now to do this I've written this code:

```
var date_start_temp = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
console.log(date_start_temp)
var date_start = date_start_temp.clone().utc().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var date_end = date_start.clone().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

The console.log returns this:

> Tue Nov 10 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)

but in the next line I get this error:

> date_start_temp.clone(...).utc is not a function

and I don't know why. I just want to get this final result:

**date_start**

> Tue Nov 10 2015 00:00:00

**date_end**

> Wed Nov 11 2015 00:00:00

How you can see I've set the hours to 0 and remove the GMT, I don't want the GMT. How I can achieve this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a Date object in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm using momentjs no date object of javascript, read the post first.

Comment: Are you sure `.start` returns a momentjs object? Doesn't look like it, otherwise you wouldn't get an error.

Comment: Yeah it does. I've printed the result in chrome console

Comment: That just tells you that the value represents a date. I get a similar output if I do `console.log(new Date())`. So I would say, pass the value to momentjs *before* you are trying to clone it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but in the next line I get this error [...] and I don't know why.

[`.clone` is a method of Moment.js.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) `.start` doesn't seem to return a Moment.js instance, so you cannot call `.clone` on it.

Pass the value to `moment` first:

```
var date_start = moment(date_start_temp).utc().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Okay and for date_end? How you can see I've: var date_end = date_start.clone().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");

Comment: Pretty much the same: `moment(date_start_temp).utc().startOf('day').add(1, 'day').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: the date returned at the end is: Tue Nov 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100, I want remove +0100 'cause add an hour in my timezone how I can do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The way you format the data it won't show the timezone. Of course the underlying date object still contains timezone information.