# How to add a number of days to UTC now in JS?

Tags: javascript, date

I've read a bunch of the related questions but just can't figure this one out.

This is what i have:

```
var days = "10"; // input is in string
var now = new Date();
var nowUtc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var newDate = nowUtc.setDate(nowUtc.getDate() + parseInt(days));
```

The values just don't seem correct so i must be doing it wrong. Can anyone help?

I want the value in the end to be ISO 8601 format.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `nowUtc.setDate()` changes `nowUtc` in place, and returns a *number*, not a date.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of add number of days? This question specifically mentions UTC, whilst the linked answer does not.

Comment: The `var nowUtc = new Date(...)` statement uses UTC values for input, but the Date constructor expects local values so applies the current host timezone offset, hence you get unexpected results. To copy a Date instance *date*, just use `new Date(date)`.

Comment: Figured it out: `var now = new Date;
      var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate() + parseInt(days), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes()));`

Comment: @RPM1984—see comment above for how to copy a Date, it's much simpler than using *Date.UTC*. You could also use `new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), …)` but only if you're being paid for your code by length. ;-)

Comment: There's already an answer for [*How to clone a Date object in JavaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript). ;-)

Comment: @nnnnnn i can't post an answer, because this was closed as dupe

Answer (score 2):

`setDate` changes the Date object itself. you can use `nowUtc.toISOString()` to get ISO 8601 string.

```
nowUtc.setDate(nowUtc.getDate() + parseInt(days));
var iso = nowUtc.toISOString();
```

Comment: But i want to add days? Isn't that why i need `setDate`?

Answer (score -1):

Just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - a library which simplifies DateTime manipulation in JavaScript.

What you are looking for is [Add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) function and [String function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

I hope it helps you!