# Javascript Date behaving in two different ways

Tags: javascript, datetime, vue.js

I have a Vue js frontend where I have the following while loop with the following:

```
while (this.day.getDay() != 0) {
  console.log(this.day)
  this.days.push(this.day)
  this.dates.push(this.day.toDateString())
  this.day.setDate(this.day.getDate() + 1)
}
```

The loop outputs the following in the console.
[image: The output is this]

I instantiate the variables as:

```
day: new Date(Date.now()),
dates: [],
days:[]
```

I'm wondering why the dates array works correctly and contains sep 6, sep7 and sep 8 but the days array only has sep 09 three times? It is also strange that when I log this.day it logs the correct days but then does not add that to the days array. What is going on here?

Comment: the name `day` is confusing since it is a `Date`, not a day of the date.

Comment: You're pushing a reference to a Date object that you mutate, but the date strings won't change.

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript, let someone else agree

Comment: @lealceldeiro I was originally going to do this.day.getDay() to add the day to the array. I decided that adding the date object would be more useful and hadn't got to changing the variable name yet since it wasn't working . I appreciate the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute this line:

```
this.days.push(this.day)
```

You keep pushing *the same Date object each time*. You never re-assign `this.day`, you only mutate it with `setDate`, and every time you do so all the references in that array are updated.

But when you run this line:

```
this.dates.push(this.day.toDateString())
```

You are capturing the state at the moment in time you push, strings are immutable.

For a simpler example of what you're getting, look at this

```
const foo = {bar: 3};
const arr = [foo, foo, foo]; // all the same foo
arr.map(x => x.bar); // 3, 3, 3
foo.bar = 5;
arr.map(x => x.bar); // 5, 5, 5
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I feel dumb for not realizing that. Would the best way to solve the problem be to clone a new Date into the array as shown in @epascarello's link that he posted?

Comment: @Taylor yeah, I'd clone it off, or use a different approach altogether (e.g. not OO).