# reactjs Count down component returns NaN on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a component which performs a hh:mm:ss countdown for my project. first I used [this](https://github.com/ndresx/react-countdown/) library for calculating and rendering time for me. it worked perfect on any devices but iOS which return

> NaN:NaN:NaN

.
I assumed it's a problem with this module so I tried to implement my own countdown component. so I tried the code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Countdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            days: 0,
            hours: 0,
            min: 0,
            sec: 0
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // update every second
        let i = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            let date = this.calculateCountdown(this.props.date, ++i);
            date ? this.setState(date) : this.stop();
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.stop();
    }

    calculateCountdown(endDate , count) {
        let diff = (endDate - (count * 1000)) / 1000;
        // clear countdown when date is reached
        if (diff <= 0) return false;

        const timeLeft = {
            years: 0,
            days: 0,
            hours: 0,
            min: 0,
            sec: 0,
            millisec: 0
        };

        // calculate time difference between now and expected date
        if (diff >= (365.25 * 86400)) { // 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60
            timeLeft.years = Math.floor(diff / (365.25 * 86400));
            diff -= timeLeft.years * 365.25 * 86400;
        }
        if (diff >= 86400) { // 24 * 60 * 60
            timeLeft.days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
            diff -= timeLeft.days * 86400;
        }
        if (diff >= 3600) { // 60 * 60
            timeLeft.hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
            diff -= timeLeft.hours * 3600;
        }
        if (diff >= 60) {
            timeLeft.min = Math.floor(diff / 60);
            diff -= timeLeft.min * 60;
        }
        timeLeft.sec = Math.floor(diff);

        return timeLeft;
    }

    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    addLeadingZeros(value) {
        value = String(value);
        while (value.length < 2) {
            value = '0' + value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    convertToPersianNumber = (time) => {
        let persianDigits = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
        let persianMap = persianDigits.split('');
        return time.replace(/\d/g, m => persianMap[parseInt(m)]);
    };

    render() {
        const countDown = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="Countdown">
                <span className="Countdown-col">
                    <span className="Countdown-col-element">
                        {countDown.hour}
                        {/*{this.convertToPersianNumber(this.addLeadingZeros(countDown.hours))}:*/}
                    </span>
                </span>

                <span className="Countdown-col">
                      <span className="Countdown-col-element">
                          {countDown.min}
                          {/*{this.convertToPersianNumber(this.addLeadingZeros(countDown.min))}:*/}
                      </span>
                </span>

                <span className="Countdown-col">
                      <span className="Countdown-col-element">
                          {countDown.sec}
                          {/*{this.convertToPersianNumber(this.addLeadingZeros(countDown.sec))}*/}
                      </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Countdown.propTypes = {
    date: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

Countdown.defaultProps = {
    date: 0
};

export default Countdown;
```

in this component I pass my end time in mili seconds and calculate time by an interval , finally I convert it to persian strings and print it.

```
<div className={styles.bottomContainer}>
                    {/*<Moment>{remainTime}</Moment>*/}
    <CountDown onComplete={() => this.setState({ timerEnd: true })}
               date={remainTime}/>
</div>
```

I still have the same problem I had before: in iOS devices I get

> NaN:00:00

what is my problem if you can help me?
I have to add that I cleared converting and tried to printing just numbers and it didn't work;

Comment: It works on other devices, but not on iOS?

Comment: @LazarNikolic yes

Comment: Please show how you're using the `Countdown` element. We need to see the `date` prop supplied. But note that your `propTypes` says it's a number, while your default makes it a `Date` object. `new Date(dateInstance)` was [not historically reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript#comment47658106_1090817), although the spec now says it should work and it works on my iPad. But the default should be a number if you're saying it's a number with `propTypes`: `Date.now()`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated the question. I edited the component which I removed all Date functions and calculates using another way. and also I added the use of Countdown instance

Comment: All that does is beg the question: What's `remainTime`?! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder remainTime is a value in miliSeconds for example 1784000

Comment: @T.J.Crowder finally your first answer helped me. I wish you could redo its removing

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi - Really? I thought `date` was a number, so that answer wouldn't be correct. I've un-deleted it, but ... does it really answer the question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, outside the Countdown Component, I was converting a date to milisecond using Date.parse(). argument inside this function was not in correct format and I fixed it using your hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're relying on `new Date` to parse the `date` string. You haven't shown us what format that string is in, but the **only** format that `new Date` is required to parse is [the ISO-8601-inspired one](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) defined in the specification, such as `"2018-09-09T09:46:33.089Z"` (that's just an example). All modern browsers are also known to parse the U.S. format `"MM/DD/YYYY"` (regardless of locale), but that **isn't** specified. iOS Safari is known not to handle some formats that other browsers do handle.

So, either:

- Ensure you use the ISO-8601 format when specifying `date`, or
- Parse the string yourself

Comment: I'm passing `endDate` to `new Date(endDate)` . this variable is in miliseconds

Comment: (Undeleted per OP's request.)