# Date parameter in function

Tags: javascript, date

I want to pass a date to a javascript function for some manipulation. The problem I am facing here is: the function is changing the actual date parameter though it works on a local parameter. Here is an example where I have mentioned my issue

```
var myDate = new Date();
console.log(myDate);//Result is Mon Oct 22 2018 09:40:01
function manipulate(d){
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    console.log(d);//Result is Oct 23 2018 09:40:01
    return d;
}
var result = manipulate(myDate);
console.log(result);//Result is Oct 23 2018 09:40:01 as expected.
console.log(myDate);//Result is Oct 23 2018 09:40:01. I want this to be my initial value. That is Mon Oct 22 2018 09:40:01
```

I guess it JS uses pass by reference if the date is used as a parameter. 
How can I resolve the above-mentioned issue?

Regards,

SAP Learner

Comment: Try to take a copy of date in the function as follows:

    var dLocalCopyFrom = new Date(d.getTime());
    dLocalCopyFrom.setDate(dLocalCopyFrom.getDate()+1);

This will not alter the actual date

Comment: Use the Date object's getTime() function to get a clone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy it first

```
function manipulate(d){
    var s = new Date(d)
    s.setDate(s.getDate()+1);
    console.log(s);//Result is Oct 23 2018 09:40:01
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `new Date(d)` is sufficient.