# How to avoid the original variable being reset in this js date sum

Tags: javascript

I have this simple javascript function to sum a date

```
    console.log(this.state.birth_date)  //logs birth date

    var death_date = this.state.birth_date.setFullYear(this.state.birth_date.getFullYear() + this.state.years_to_live) 

    console.log(this.state.birth_date) //logs death date
    console.log(death_date) //logs death date
```

How to avoid the birth date being set as death date after the  death date is set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var birth = new Date();
var death = new Date(birth.getTime())

death.setFullYear(birth.getFullYear() + 100);

console.log('Birth: ' + birth);
console.log('Death: ' + death);
```