# Problem while referencing javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem here where after assigning a date to the variable newRecurrDate when I change the value of newRecurrDate the value of date is also changed and I get value in variable time as zero. I understand that newRecurrDate is referring to date address and hence I face problems. How to copy the value so that I won't face any issue?

```
      getDaysFromGivenMonth : function (date, months) {
        var newRecurrDate = date;
        newRecurrDate.add(months, 'months');  // NO I18N
        var time = newRecurrDate - moment(date);
```

Comment: Try using var newRecurrDate=Object.assign({},date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object)

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: @mgm793 yus it does helped

Answer (score 1):

Use `moment.clone` to create a copy of a moment object.

```
var newRecurrDate = date.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitute

```
var newRecurrDate = date;
```

by

```
var newRecurrDate = new Date(date.getTime());
```

This creates a own date object instead of another reference to the same date object.