# JS new Date() object is unexpectedly synchronised elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I want to store two values in an object: `today`, `todayInOneYear`. I use a function to calculate the +1 year.

```js
obj = {}
today = new Date();

obj = {
  today: today,
  oneYear: addOneYear(today)
}
console.log(obj)

function addOneYear(date) {
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
  return date;
}
```

**Problem:** Today and todayInOneYear are the same. But I expect two different dates. Once from now (today) and then once from a year from now. Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm confused: if *"Today and todayInOneYear are the same. I am not aware that I made a deep copy"* then why *"therefore I expect two different dates"*?

Comment: _“I am not aware that I made a deep copy. Therefore I expect two different dates.”_ — Huh? Did you mean the opposite of that statement? You need to clone the Date, resulting in two objects instead of one, if you want two different dates. See [How to clone a Date object?](/q/1090815/4642212) and [Modifying a copy of a JavaScript object is causing the original object to change](/q/29050004/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon You are right. Sorry for my english. I updated my question. Thank you and Gerado for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090815/how-to-clone-a-date-object) the Date object:

```js
obj = {}
today = new Date();

obj = {
  today: today,
  oneYear: addOneYear(today)
}
console.log(obj)

function addOneYear(date) {
  let clone = new Date(date);
  clone.setFullYear(clone.getFullYear() + 1);
  return clone;
}
```

Comment: While this is true, this can’t be the answer to the _real_ question, can it? Otherwise this would just need to be closed as a duplicate of [How to clone a Date object?](/q/1090815/4642212)…

Comment: One more question: why i will get a timestamp when i return directly `return clone.setFullYear(clone.getFullYear() + 1);`

Comment: @MaikLowrey That’s what [`setFullYear`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) returns.

Comment: yes sorry i mean it returns a unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```js
obj = {}
today = new Date();

obj = {
  today: today,
  oneYear: addOneYear(today)
}
console.log(obj)
function addOneYear(date) {
  const aYearFromNow = new Date(date);
  aYearFromNow.setFullYear(aYearFromNow.getFullYear() + 1);
    console.log(aYearFromNow)
  return aYearFromNow;
}
```