# I want controls to be populated

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two date controls. When the page loads, I have to set end date as current date and start date as one week from current date. How to do this? I have to use only JavaScript. How to populate these two controls when the page loads?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get the current date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531093/215552) and [how to get next week date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1025693/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get next week date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025693/how-to-get-next-week-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this : 
http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

his documentation has almost everything covered.

you'll definitely feel at ease with this tool..

Comment: and if your problem was only related to converting dates, then download dateJS and use it.

Comment: no. i already have the calendar control. How to populate the start and end date on page loading, with end date as today's date and start date as one week before current date.

Comment: just add the date as "value" into the text box in the exact format the calendar gives you... :)
for easy manipulation of dates, you could work your way with http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp  
or use dateJS

Comment: I mean like this : <input type="text" value="2011-1-1" />
or whatever weird format your calendar is currently programmed to display..

Comment: @Vinodh : and which calendar control are you using by the way

Comment: @Shrinath : i'm using calendar control in sap. Here you have hard coded the value of date, but i dont want to hard code. It has to be fetched.

Comment: @Vinodh : I was answering with jquery calendar in mind, my mistake..!

why don't you simulate the click event with those dates ?

Comment: @Shrinath : i'm not that much good working in html pages, that is the reason i'm struggling a bit. I've written on page_load function : document.getElementById("testinput2").value=Date(); This gets me the value as Mon Feb 02/07/2011 where as the possible input can only be 02/07/2011.

Comment: @Vinodh : use this : `var date = new Date();
var today = date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("testinput").value=today;`

read it from here : http://jsfiddle.net/tTgqH/

Comment: This is a link to an answer, not an answer. [Edit] it to include the relevant information from your conversation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Date()` javascript object.

```
// current date
var currentDate = new Date();
var time = currentDate.getTime();
```