# Get Monday date of the upcoming week

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the date of Monday of the upcoming week, so for example, if I run the script now I will get 2021-09-13.

I tried solving this myself, and wrote this:

```
export function getMondayDate() {
  const d = new Date();
  const DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;

  var today = d.getDay()


  const daysToMonday = (DAYS_IN_WEEK - today) + 1;
  const Monday = d.getDate() + d.getDay() + daysToMonday;

  return new Date(d.setDate(Monday));
}
```

I thought about getting the current day, so for example `getDay()` will return `3`.

So, when subtracting `DAYS_IN_WEEK` from `today`, will result in the number `4` that would get Sunday and than to add `1` to get Monday.
So, from Today, it will be `5` days to get to Monday.

But for some reason I get the wrong date, I can't really see what's wrong here.

Comment: What do you expect when today is Sunday? Tomorrow? Or 8 days later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get next week's date of a certain day in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582087/get-next-weeks-date-of-a-certain-day-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add `d.getDay()` to `d.getDate()`. You have already used `d.getDate()` to determine `daysToMonday`, so you should not use it *again*.

Secondly, if you want on a Sunday to get the next day as return value (instead of one week later), then you should add a `% 7` in the formula.

Currently your function will return a date with a time part that is equal to the current time. Maybe you want to reset the time part to 0.

```js
function getMondayDate() {
  const d = new Date();
  const daysToMonday = (7 - d.getDay()) % 7 + 1;
  const monday = d.getDate() + daysToMonday;

  return new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), monday);
}

console.log(getMondayDate().toString());
```

Comment: was going to close it as duplicate :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43582700/17447

Comment: While the JS Date constructor attempts to correct invalid day of month values (e.g. potential overflows like in your code example), is it wise to rely on that behavior?

Comment: @jsejcksn, this behaviour is baked into the [ECMAScript language specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-constructor). We can rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.prototype.getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the day in the week. From there, you have enough information to get when's the next monday.

E.g.

```js
const nowMs = Date.now();
const today = new Date(nowMs);

/*
The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday
*/
const dayOfTheWeek = today.getDay();

// Monday is 1st day of the week, so..
const itsSunday = dayOfTheWeek === 0;
let deltaDayToMonday;

if (itsSunday) {
  deltaDayToMonday = 1; // monday is tomorrow
}
else {
  deltaDayToMonday = 8 - dayOfTheWeek;
}

console.log(`Monday is in ${deltaDayToMonday} day(s)`);

/*
We're using the milliseconds to generate the new date for monday
To handle the dates overflowing months or years
*/
const nextMondayInMs = nowMs + (deltaDayToMonday * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
const nextMondayUtc = new Date(nextMondayInMs);

console.log("Next monday is", nextMondayUtc.toLocaleString());
```